# SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'doDelete' is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have the following page with JS.

```
<html>
<script language="Javascript" type="application/javascript">
function doDelete(myid)
{
    if(confirm("Are you sure want to delete this Attendance?"))
    {
        window.location.href="AttDelete.asp?id="+myid;
    }
}
</Script>

<body>



66


<a href="" onClick="doDelete(44)"> Delete</a>       

</body>
</html>
```

It works find in Firefox, but throws the following error in IE9. Please advise.

> SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'doDelete' is null or undefined,
>   not a Function object

Thanks

Comment: Where is the function being used?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are calling the function but as of now what I can advice is that the `<script type="text/javascript" />` is more reliable than `<script type="application/javascript" />`